# Include current date into generated JavaDoc

Tags: java, jautodoc

I am using [jAutodoc](http://jautodoc.sourceforge.net/) to generate JavaDocs automatically. Here is an example:

```
/**
## type: class|interface|enum
 * The ${e.getType().fu()} ${e}.
 * 
 * 
 * @author Edson 
 * @version 1.0.0
 * @date    11/09/2015
 * 
 */
```

My question is, how can I include the current date into the generated JavaDoc comment?

I tried:

```
 * @date    new java.util.Date();
```

However, it has no effect.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use:

```
${date} -> for the date
${time} -> for the time
```

Regards,
Alain

Answer (score 2):

If you use `${date}` it will print the current date.